# Run-time error '1004' Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed

Tags: excel, range, vba

I have a macro that fills in some data at the `DataCell` location and a few other cells based on the information it finds on the master sheet.  Once it finds a "blank" on the master sheet it stops.  I then want it to select a range on my 'data' sheet and clear the contents of that range.

For some reason I get an error in trying to select the needed range.  The code dies at:

```
Range("EmptyCell:AZ24").Select
```

I just need it to properly select the first part of the range. This first cell will vary depending on other portions of the macro.

I have looked through your other answers to similar problems and haven't been able to resolve the issue.

```
Set DataCell = cnsu2table.Offset(0, x + 1)
    If DataCell <> "" Then
    DataCell.Offset(-2, 0) = cnsu2por
    DataCell.Offset(-1, 0) = cnsu2fcr
    DataCell.Offset(1, 0) = Application.WorksheetFunction.HLookup(DataCell, cnsu2array, 51, False)
    ElseIf DataCell = "" Then
        Set EmptyCell = DataCell.Offset(-2, 0)
        Range("EmptyCell:AZ24").ClearContents
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
Range("EmptyCell:AZ24").ClearContents
```

By:

```
Range(EmptyCell.Address & ":AZ24").ClearContents
```

You should also declare your `EmptyCell` variable as:

```
Dim EmptyCell as Range
```

before using it.

`EmptyCell` is a variable so putting it between quotation marks will not return the variable but will return the string "EmptyCell" not the object `EmptyCell`.

Answer (score 0):

Use instead:

```
Range(EmptyCell, Range("AZ24")).ClearContents
```